# Couchbase Eventing Service seems to be in a rolling boot

Tags: couchbase

Having an issue with getting the eventing service running on my couchbase cluster.  The service has been added to the nodes and re-introduced back into the cluster but keep getting the following error in the log.  Its almost like the service is in a rolling boot...

```
Service ‘eventing’ exited with status 1. Restarting. Messages:
2021-02-02T14:55:40.617+00:00 [Info] SuperSupervisor::TopologyChangeNotifCallback [0] Path => /eventing/rebalanceToken/124c0ffc26ade9f4d57b82f678e9e802 value => 124c0ffc26ade9f4d57b82f678e9e802
2021-02-02T14:55:40.619+00:00 [Info] SuperSupervisor::GlobalConfigChangeCallback [0] Path => /eventing/settings/config value => {“enable_debugger”:false,“ram_quota”:972}
2021-02-02T14:55:40.619+00:00 [Info] SuperSupervisor::HandleGlobalConfigChange [0] Config key: enable_debugger value: false
2021-02-02T14:55:40.619+00:00 [Info] SuperSupervisor::HandleGlobalConfigChange [0] Config key: ram_quota value: 972
2021-02-02T14:55:40.625+00:00 [Info] servicesChangeNotifier: Creating new notifier instance for http://%40eventing-cbauth@127.0.0.1:8091, default
2021-02-02T14:55:40.627+00:00 [Info] serviceChangeNotifier: received ServiceChangeNotification
2021-02-02T14:55:40.627+00:00 [Info] SuperSupervisor::TopologyChangeNotifCallback [0] Apps in primary store: [], running apps: map[]
2021-02-02T14:55:40.630+00:00 [Info] serviceChangeNotifier: received PoolChangeNotification
```

Comment: What version of Couchbase Server is this?

Comment: @mattgroves enterprise server 6.6.1 after stopping and starting couchbase on all the codes we are now past the issue in the log message above but are now seeing an issue when we try to rebalance, the eventing service fails rebalance... with this error       <\"failed to get active eventing nodes in the cluster\">>}}}]}}},\n                 [{service_rebalancer,rebalance_worker,1,\n                  [{file,\"src/service_rebalancer.erl\"},\n                  {line,164}]},\n

Answer (score 1):

Found that there was a port blocked, once added to security group, all worked as desired.  Please refer to couchbase documentation on ports required per service...

https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/install/install-ports.html

Eventing ports include:

8096 (HTTP) / 18096 (SSL) / 9140 (debug)